# Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables.How to avoid this prompt?

Tags: equation-solving

```
Clear["Global`*"];
a = {0, 0, 0};
b = {2, 0, 0};
c = {0, 2, 0};
a1 = {-1, 0, Sqrt[3]};
b1 = {1, 0, Sqrt[3]};
c1 = {-1, 2, Sqrt[3]};
d = {0, 0, Sqrt[3]};
eq = b1 + n1 (c1 - b1) + n2 (a1 - b1) == a + m1 (b1 - a) + m2 (c - a)
sol = First@Solve[eq, {n1, n2, m1, m2}]
```

What is the reason for this prompt when using solve to solve the vector equation above? How to avoid such prompts?

[image]

Comment: You have 4 unknowns and 3 equations - see the [**docs**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/Solve/svars.html#:~:text=This%20message%20is%20generated%20when,be%20determined%20from%20the%20equations.). If you try to create 4 equations for example do you still get an message?

Comment: @bmf This prompt turns out to have more unknowns than equations，thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing `Solve` by `Reduce` succeeds.

```
sol = Reduce[eq, {n1, n2, m1, m2}]
```

> `n2 == -n1 && m1 == 1 && m2 == n1`